# Suitable components for Person List. Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm quite new to android studio so be easy please.
For now I'm doing my best to implement MVVM pattern using Kotlin.
I want an app which is shows Persons in a list (For now I'm using Recycle View with a Text View inside). I want user to be able to tap on a Person and after tap Person card would pop up. The questions are:

1. Which component should I use instead of Text View to observe user's tap?
2. Which components should I use for Person card? Person(Name, Last name, Age, Avatar(jpg img))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can just use the text view.  Just set an onClickListener to know when someone taps it.
2. Depends on the exact UI you want.  A dialog might fit, with whatever you want inside it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was thinking about 2 separate fragments, one for for Persons list to choose Person and a second fragment as a Person card, so I guess I need 2 View Models for each fragment?